# JavaScript / PHP echo selected image from array

Tags: javascript

By clicking on the button `onclick="nextPic()"` I am able to change image to the next one in the array `myPictures` by changing the `img:src` with `id="target"`. Is there a way to also echo the value of whichever image is  displayed when the button is clicked?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <img id="target" src="http://www.java2s.com/style/download.png" width="107" height="98" />
    <input type="button" onclick="nextPic()" value="change image" />

    <script>
        var target = document.getElementById('target');
        var counter = 0;
        var myPictures = [
            "http://www.bildersuche.org/images/logos/pixabay-logo.png",
            "http://www.bildersuche.org/images/logos/123rf-logo.jpg",
            "http://www.java2s.com/style/download.png"
        ];

        function nextPic() {
            counter += 1;
            if (counter > myPictures.length -1) {
                counter = 0;
            }
            target.src = myPictures[counter];
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
    var target = document.getElementById('target');
    var counter = 0;
    var myPictures = [
        "http://www.bildersuche.org/images/logos/pixabay-logo.png",
        "http://www.bildersuche.org/images/logos/123rf-logo.jpg",
        "http://www.java2s.com/style/download.png"
    ];
    var values = [
        "A",
        "B",
        "C"
    ]

    function nextPic() {
      counter += 1;
      if (counter > myPictures.length -1) {
        counter = 0;
      }
      target.src = myPictures[counter];
      caption.innerHTML = values[counter];
    }
```

```html
<figure>
<img id="target" src="http://www.java2s.com/style/download.png" width="107" height="98" />
<figcaption id="caption"></figcaption>
</figure>
  <input type="button" onclick="nextPic()" value="change image" />
```